# Issue while saving data

Tags: ios, save, codenameone, savechanges

In my Codename One project I have a data file which is created while loading the application. The file can be updated with the application also. In the android version there are no problems, data can be written and read without any problems. In the IOS version, this isn't the case. It worked faultless till 15 days ago. Now, when I save data, the app pretends as if everything is alright but if I exit the application and start over, the data is not there.

I didn't change the code and it is the same for IOS and Android. So I guess the problem lies within the permissions. Are there any hints for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `ios.newStorageLocation` is defined to `true` in the build hints.

Comment: I have tried that out in the iosdebug build version. But it did not help. Can there be any difference between debug build and release build?

Comment: No but it's possible that if you didn't have that setup properly you won't have the data the first time around. If this still doesn't work I'll need to understand how you use storage.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ios.newStorageLocation to true was not sufficient.

Using *Storage.getInstance().flushStorageCache();* has solved the problem.